# "Module 'tensorflow.python.distribute.values' has no attribute 'AutoPolicy'" from importing Tensorflow Hub

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I've been trying to run [this TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/classify_text_with_bert) on my computer, but while running the following code I've been getting the error from the title:

```py
import os
import shutil

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text
from official.nlp import optimization  # to create AdamW optmizer

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
```

This is the entire error traceback. While running it in the tutorial's Collab notebook there doesn't seem any problem whatsoever.

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3afaa91eeb1f> in <module>
      3 
      4 import tensorflow as tf
----> 5 import tensorflow_hub as hub
      6 import tensorflow_text as text
      7 from official.nlp import optimization  # to create AdamW optmizer

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py in <module>
     86 
     87 
---> 88 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
     89 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import register_module_for_export
     90 from tensorflow_hub.feature_column import image_embedding_column

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py in <module>
     60 
     61 
---> 62 class LatestModuleExporter(tf.compat.v1.estimator.Exporter):
     63   """Regularly exports registered modules into timestamped directories.
     64 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    124                 break
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 
    128 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/api/_v1/estimator/__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import experimental
     11 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import export
     12 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/api/_v1/estimator/experimental/__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
     11 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.kmeans import KMeansClustering as KMeans
     12 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.linear import LinearSDCA

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py in <module>
     29 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import losses_utils
     30 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import estimator_export
---> 31 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
     32 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned import head as head_lib
     33 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned import optimizers

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in <module>
     50 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import estimator_export
     51 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
---> 52 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import run_config
     53 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import util as estimator_util
     54 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.export import export_lib

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/run_config.py in <module>
     28 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
     29 from tensorflow.python.distribute import estimator_training as distribute_coordinator_training
---> 30 from tensorflow.python.distribute import parameter_server_strategy_v2
     31 from tensorflow.python.util import compat_internal
     32 from tensorflow.python.util import function_utils

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/parameter_server_strategy_v2.py in <module>
     26 
     27 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_lib
---> 28 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_utils
     29 from tensorflow.python.distribute import parameter_server_strategy
     30 from tensorflow.python.distribute import sharded_variable

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_utils.py in <module>
    372 # (synchronization=ON_READ, aggregation=NONE,SUM,MEAN,ONLY_FIRST_REPLICA)
    373 VARIABLE_POLICY_MAPPING = {
--> 374     vs.VariableSynchronization.AUTO: values_lib.AutoPolicy,
    375     vs.VariableSynchronization.ON_WRITE: values_lib.OnWritePolicy,
    376     vs.VariableSynchronization.ON_READ: values_lib.OnReadPolicy,

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.distribute.values' has no attribute 'AutoPolicy'
```

Is there any particular reason as to why is this happening?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this could be related to a version mismatch between the versions you're using for `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_hub`.

It looks like AutoPolicy was removed from TF in [a recent commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/0ac07a2fc45e5613c5f6fa5cfabe5e2e49f555a9), so if you built tensorflow from source and included this commit, then that could be the issue. If you want to build TF from source, checkout the latest official release before building ([2.4.1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v2.4.1)).